# Single text overlapping over elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following codes

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6"><img src = "<?php echo $photo ?>"/><?php echo $row['comment'];?></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

which produces this: http://d.pr/i/g4y7

Why would the text "thissssssss..sss" overlap the other span while the text "this this this" with spaces display just fine?

The expected result is the first part of the text. The problem is the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the browser does not know how to wrap this long word.

You have to declare:

```
 <element> { word-wrap: break-word }
```

to avoid this.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` breaks strings into pieces.